# c++ pthreads opertions on a global char buffer

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am experimenting with pthreads. I am trying to create three threads and have them operate on a global char buffer. I am using mutex lock and unlock for their critical sections. The program flow should go: Main spawns three threads. Thread one locks, initializes the buffer, prints it out, signals thread two, and unlocks. Thread two enters its critical section operates on the buffer and signals thread three, etc. It seems to work, sometimes. Other times, it seems like it is getting suck in a spin lock. Any help in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

```
#include <pthread.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int num_threads = 3;

char buffer[100]; 
pthread_mutex_t buffer_mutex = pthread_mutex_initializer; 
pthread_cond_t buffer_cond = pthread_cond_initializer;



void* firstthreadfunc(void* proc) { 
    string a = "data received";
    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);

    sleep(1);
    cout<<"threadone"<<endl;    
    for(int i = 0;i<14;i++){
        buffer[i] = a[i];
        cout<<buffer[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;

    pthread_cond_signal(&buffer_cond);   

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
    return null; 
} 

void* secondthreadfunc(void* proc) { 
    string a = "data processed"; 

    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_cond, &buffer_mutex);

    sleep(1);
    cout<<"threadtwo"<<endl;        
    for(int i = 0; i<15 ;i++){
        buffer[i] = a[i];
        cout<<buffer[i];
    }   
    cout<<endl;  

    pthread_cond_signal(&buffer_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
    return null; 
}

void* thirdthreadfunc(void* proc) { 

    string a = "data sent";
    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_cond, &buffer_mutex); 
    sleep(1);

    cout<<"thread three"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0;i<9;i++){
        buffer[i] = a[i];
        cout<<buffer[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;

    pthread_cond_signal(&buffer_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
    return null; 
}


int main() {

    pthread_t  p_threadone, p_threadtwo, p_threadthree;;

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    for(int i = 0;i<100;i++){
        buffer[i] = 'a';
    }


    //create threads
    cout<<"creating threads"<<endl; 
    pthread_create(&p_threadone, &attr, firstthreadfunc, null);
    pthread_create(&p_threadtwo, &attr, secondthreadfunc, null);
    pthread_create(&p_threadthree, &attr, thirdthreadfunc, null);


    //terminate threads
    pthread_join(p_threadone,null);
    pthread_join(p_threadtwo,null);
    pthread_join(p_threadthree,null);



    return 0;




}
```

Thanks WhozCraig and Tony, your answers resolved the issue. I understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that. Let me know if thats any better.

Comment: 1) why do you expect secondThreadFunc to run before thirdThreadFunc, given they're using the same condition variable? 2) condition variables can be signaled spontaneously - you're supposed to have a loop to check the condition before proceeding

Comment: Tony, thanks for the comment. Okay that makes perfect sense. How can I check in the loop for the pthread_cond_t variables to change? Sorry if thats a dumb question I'm just learning this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, where you're stuck. The following line in either thread2 or thread3 is the sticking point:

```
pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_cond, &buffer_mutex);
```

And by now you're asking, "Why?" Because your mistaking a condition variable as a state; not a *signaling* mechanism. Condition variables are intended to be used to signal interested waiters of  change in state of *something else*: the **predicate**. You have none. Consider the following modified version of your code.

This uses two predicate values (I advise you stick with one per condvar until you become more comfortable with them; start simple), protecting them with the same mutex and signaling their change with the same condition variable. The important thing to note is that we don't wait on the condition variable until we *know* the predicate we're waiting for is not ready yet. And since we have the mutex locked, we can safely do check that predicate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_THREADS = 3;

char buffer[100];
bool bDataReady = false;
bool bDataWaiting = false;

pthread_mutex_t buffer_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t buffer_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


void* firstThreadFunc(void* proc)
{
    string a = "Data Received";

    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);
    cout<<"ThreadOne"<<endl;
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), buffer);
    buffer[a.size()] = 0;
    cout << buffer << endl;

    bDataReady = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&buffer_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
    return NULL;
}

void* secondThreadFunc(void* proc)
{
    string a = "Data Processed";

    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);
    while (!bDataReady)
        pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_cond, &buffer_mutex);

    cout<<"ThreadTwo"<<endl;
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), buffer);
    buffer[a.size()] = 0;
    cout << buffer << endl;

    bDataReady = false;
    bDataWaiting = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&buffer_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
    return NULL;
}

void* thirdThreadFunc(void* proc) 
{
    string a = "Data Sent";
    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);

    while (!bDataWaiting)
        pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_cond, &buffer_mutex);

    cout<<"Thread Three"<<endl;
    std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), buffer);
    buffer[a.size()] = 0;
    cout << buffer << endl;

    bDataWaiting = false;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&buffer_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
    return NULL;
}


int main() {

    pthread_t  p_threadOne, p_threadTwo, p_threadThree;;

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    for(int i = 0;i<100;i++){
        buffer[i] = 'a';
    }


    //create Threads
    cout<<"creating threads"<<endl;
    pthread_create(&p_threadOne, &attr, firstThreadFunc, NULL);
    pthread_create(&p_threadTwo, &attr, secondThreadFunc, NULL);
    pthread_create(&p_threadThree, &attr, thirdThreadFunc, NULL);


    //terminate Threads
    pthread_join(p_threadOne,NULL);
    pthread_join(p_threadTwo,NULL);
    pthread_join(p_threadThree,NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
creating threads
ThreadOne
Data Received
ThreadTwo
Data Processed
Thread Three
Data Sent
```